# Reset DNS Settings Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dns, ubuntu-16.04

Something went wrong with my DNS settings on Ubuntu 16.04.

I can get access to the internet using Chrome but Firefox, Terminal and everything else can't.

What could be happening and how do I reset the DNS settings?